# How prove this inequality $(\sum a_{1}^{1.5})^2\ge \sum a_{1}\sum a_{1}a_{2}$

Tags: inequality

Now my question let $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$ are positive numbers,and $a_{n+i}=a_{i},i=1,2,\cdots$,show that

$$(\sum a_{1}^{1.5})^2\ge \sum a_{1}\sum a_{1}a_{2}$$

my teacher (tian275461) have prove this
$$(a^{1.5}+b^{1.5}+c^{1.5})^2\ge (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ac)$$

He methods:let $a\longrightarrow a^2,b\longrightarrow b^2,c\longrightarrow c^2$
then
$$\Longleftrightarrow (a^3+b^3+c^3)^2\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^2b^2+c^2a^2+b^2c^2)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow(\sum a^3)^2\ge \sum a^2\sum a^2b^2$$

note
$$(\sum a^3)^2=\sum a^2\sum a^4-\sum b^2c^2(b-c)^2$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum a^2\left(\sum a^4-\sum a^2b^2\right)-\sum b^2c^2(b-c)^2\ge 0 $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}\sum a^2\sum(b^2-c^2)^2-\sum b^2c^2(b-c)^2\ge 0$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}(b-c)^2 \left(\sum a^2\sum (b+c)^2-2\sum b^2c^2\right) \ge 0$$

it suffices to show that
$$\sum b^2\sum (b+c)^2-2\sum b^2c^2\ge 0$$

and note that
$$\sum b^2\sum (b+c)^2-2\sum b^2c^2=2\sum a^4+2\sum a^3b+2\sum a^3c+2\sum a^2b^2+2\sum a^2bc\ge 0$$
for n=4,it only show that
$$(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)^2\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2d^2+d^2a^2)$$

Comment: The first substitution looks very promising. Maybe use cauchy-schwarz to finish up somehow?

Comment: yes, I have try $Cauchy-Schwarz$ inequality,But I can't work

Comment: @math110 For $n=4$ it's just AM-GM and P-M

Comment: In your last equivalence you cannot carry $(b-c)^2$ out of the sum.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Could you please explain what does P-M stand for?

Comment: @clark P-M it's the Power Mean inequality. $\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3}{4}}\geq\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}}$

Comment: Interestingly, $(\sum a_{1}^{1.5})^2\ge \sum a_{1}\sum a_{1}a_{3}$ does not generally hold. A counterexample is obtained, for example,  for $n=4$ and $a_1 = 1.1, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 1.1, a_4 = 1$.

Comment: I started an extended question at this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455640/)

Answer (score 2):

The conjecture is **false**.

(See my previous post for sufficient extra conditions such that the conjecture holds.)

Here is a counterexample. Let n even (n odd works as well).

Let $a_1=a_2 = \dots = a_{n/2} = A$ and $a_{n/2 +1 } = a_{n/2 +2 } = \dots = a_{n} = B$. Let, without loss of generality, $B<A$.

Then the conjecture is

$$
(\sum a_{1}^{1.5})^2 -  \sum a_{1}\sum a_{1}a_{2} = \\
\frac{n^2}{4}(A^{1.5} +B^{1.5})^2 - \frac{n}2 (A+B) ((\frac{n}2-1)(A^2+B^2) + 2 AB) \ge 0
$$

Let $B = x^2\cdot A$, (where $0<x<1$), then this transforms into

$$
n(1 +x^{3})^2 - (1+x^2) ((n-2)(1+x^4) + 4 x^2) \ge 0
$$

Expanding this gives
$$
n(2x^3 - x^2 - x^4) - 2 x^2 - 2 x^4 + 2 x^6 + 2 \ge 0 
$$

Now the factor of the leading $n$ is always negative: $2x^3 - x^2 - x^4= -( x - x^2)^2 < 0 $ for $0<x<1$. For the remaining sum terms, $2 > - 2 x^2 - 2 x^4 + 2 x^6 + 2 >0$ for $0<x<1$.

Hence the conjecture **fails** for large enough $n$, namely

$$
n  > n_0 = \frac{- 2 x^2 - 2 x^4 + 2 x^6 + 2 }{- (2x^3 - x^2 - x^4) }
$$

$
\Box
$

The following plots illustrate the magnitude of $n_0$ for two ranges of $x$. From those plots, one could conjecture, if my example is indeed the worst case,  that the proposed inequality  holds for all $n<16$. ($n=3$ and $n=4$ are proven.)

[image: n_0 = n_0(x)]

[image: n_0=n_0(x)]

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the OP's equivalence relations and  there is a problem due to sloppy sum notation. Here I added what is precisely summed up. Summing over $(b,c)$ stands for the $N(N-1)/2$ many  pairs $(b,c)$ where $b \neq c$, when the summand is symmetric under exchange of  $b,c$. For additional clarity, I added how many terms each sum  encompasses, in [brackets].

This gives a proof for $N=3$,  and it also shows why the OP's approach will not directly give results for   $N>3$.

The transformation steps are:

$$(\sum_{a \; [N]} a^3)^2=\sum_{a \; [N]} a^6 + 2 \sum_{(b,c) \; [N(N-1)/2]} b^3c^3= \sum_{a \; [N]} a^2\sum_{a \; [N]} a^4-\sum_{(b,c) \; [N(N-1)/2]} b^2c^2(b-c)^2 $$

Using this, the original question transforms into the equivalent 
$$
 \sum_{a \; [N]} a^2\left(\sum_{a \; [N]} a^4-\sum_{a_1 \; [N]} a_1^2 a_2^2\right)-\sum_{(b,c) \; [N(N-1)/2]}  b^2c^2(b-c)^2\ge 0
$$
Note in  this term, I have carefully used the notation $a_1 a_2$ which generates only $N$ many terms (as required in the original task), as compared to $(a,b)$ which would generate  $N(N-1)/2$ many terms.
$$
\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{a \; [N]} a^2\sum_{a_1 \; [N]}(a_1^2-a_2^2)^2-\sum_{(b,c) \; [N(N-1)/2]} b^2c^2(b-c)^2\ge 0
$$
A slight change leads  to 
$$
\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{a_1 \; [N]}(a_1-a_2)^2(a_1+a_2)^2 \sum_{a \; [N]} a^2-\frac12 \sum_{a_1 \; [N]} \sum_{c\neq a_1 \; [N-1]} a_1^2c^2(a_1-c)^2\ge 0
$$
and splitting off $a_2$:
$$
\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{a_1 \; [N]}(a_1-a_2)^2(a_1+a_2)^2 \sum_{a \; [N]} a^2-\sum_{a_1 \; [N]}  a_1^2a_2^2(a_1-a_2)^2\\
-\sum_{a_1 \; [N]} \sum_{c\neq a_1, a_2 \; [N-2]} a_1^2c^2(a_1-c)^2\ge 0
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{a_1 \; [N]}(a_1-a_2)^2 {\Large [} (a_1+a_2)^2 \sum_{a \; [N]} a^2- a_1^2a_2^2 {\Large ]}  \\
-\sum_{a_1 \; [N]} \sum_{c\neq a_1, a_2 \; [N-2]} a_1^2c^2(a_1-c)^2\ge 0
$$

At this point it becomes clear that this result will be difficult to use for general $N$.

For $N=3$, the last term is easily modified:

$$
\sum_{a_1 \; [N]} \sum_{c\neq a_1, a_2 \; [N-2]} a_1^2c^2(a_1-c)^2 = 
\sum_{a_1 }  a_1^2 a_3^2(a_1-a_3)^2 = \sum_{a_1 }  a_1^2 a_2^2(a_1-a_2)^2 
$$
and we have  to show 
$$
 \sum_{a_1 }(a_1-a_2)^2 {\Large [} (a_1+a_2)^2 \sum_{a } a^2- 2 a_1^2a_2^2 {\Large ]}  \ge 0
$$
which is evident since all factors 
$$
 (a_1+a_2)^2 \sum_{a } a^2- 2 a_1^2a_2^2  \ge  (a_1^2+a_2^2)(a_1^2+a_2^2)- 2 a_1^2a_2^2 = a_1^4+a_2^4\ge 0
$$

For $N=4$, the last term gives
$$
\sum_{a_1 \; [N]} \sum_{c\neq a_1, a_2 \; [N-2]} a_1^2c^2(a_1-c)^2 = 
\sum_{a_1 }  {\Large [} a_1^2 a_2^2(a_1-a_2)^2  + a_1^2 a_3^2(a_1-a_3)^2  {\Large ]}
$$
so including this term into the previous summations will not be directly possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof in the case where the $\{a_i\}$ obey a condition for the variance about their mean.

More precisely, the formulation for the above condition is the following.  Let $\bf a$  be the vector composed from the $\{a_i\}$, i.e. ${\bf a} = (a_1,a_2, \dots, a_{n-1}, a_n)$. Define the mean ${m}  = \frac1n \sum a_i$. Define a vector ${\bf m} = (m,m, \dots, m)$. Let $\bf \bar a$  be the permutation of $\bf a$ which is constructed by shifting all components cyclically by one position, i.e.  ${\bf \bar a} = (a_2,a_3, \dots, a_n, a_1)$. Then we require

$$
\cos^2({\bf a}, {\bf m})\geq \cos({\bf a}, {\bf \bar a}) 
$$

Writing this in components gives the equivalent

$$
\frac{m^2 (\sum_j a_j)^2}{n m^2 \sum_j a_j^2 } \geq \frac{\sum_j a_j a_{j+1}}{\sum_j a_j^2 }
$$
or $(\sum_j a_j)^2 \ge n  \sum_j a_j a_{j+1}$. Alternatively, one can define the difference $d_j = a_j - m$. Then we have the condition $\sum_j d_j d_{j+1} < 0$.

As an example, consider ${\bf a} = (10,9,9,1)$. Then we have 
 $(\sum_j a_j)^2 = (29)^2 = 841 \ge n  \sum_j a_j a_{j+1} = 4 \cdot(90 + 81 + 9 + 10) = 760$.

As a counterexample, consider ${\bf a} = (4,5,4,2,1,2)$. Then we have 
 $(\sum_j a_j)^2 = (18)^2 = 324 < n  \sum_j a_j a_{j+1} = 6 \cdot(20 + 20 + 8 + 2 + 2 +8) = 360$.
(Note that, nevertheless, the original inequality holds in this case.)

Now it suffices to prove, instead of the original inequality, the tighter one:

$$
n (\sum_j a_j^{1.5})^2 \ge (\sum_j a_j)^3
$$
Setting $a_j = b_j^2$ gives
$$
 (\frac1n \sum_j b_j^{3})^2 \ge (\frac1n \sum_j b_j^2)^3
$$
or 
$$
 \sqrt[3]{\frac1n \sum_j b_j^{3}} \ge \sqrt[2]{\frac1n \sum_j b_j^{2}} 
$$
but this is just the power mean inequality.$\qquad \Box$