# Does $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{1.5})^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \; \sum_{i=1}^n a_i a_{i+1} > 0$ hold for $n \leq 8$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fourier-series, rearrangement-inequality

Let positive reals $\{a_i\}$, where not all $a_i$ are equal. Does
$$
f(\{a_i\}) = (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{1.5})^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \; \sum_{i=1}^n a_i a_{i+1} > 0
$$
hold for $n \le 8$? It is understood that $a_{n+1} = a_1$.

The restriction to $n \le 8$ comes from a known counterexample for $n = 9$ given by Martin R. in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455640/): $a_i = (40, 37, 40, 50, 60, 65, 65, 56, 47)$. In there, he also gave counterexamples for higher $n$.

Further, there is a  proof for $n=3$ in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483565/)  and Michael Rozenberg has added comments in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483565/) that for $n=4$ a solution can be found by $AM-GM$ and in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455640/) that for $n=5$, Buffalo Way can produce a solution.

From the counterexamples and from numerical experiments, it appears that the solution will have to do with oscillations, so a Fourier series approach might be helpful.

Comment: Hello, maybe it could help http://vixra.org/pdf/1008.0030v1.pdf . See at theorem 2 .

Comment: @max8128 Thanks - I'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

*Remarks*: As @Michael Rozenberg pointed out, the case $n=3, 4$ can be proved nicely by the power mean inequality,
and the case $n=5$ can be proved by the Buffalo Way (BW).
Actually, the case $n=6$ can be also proved by BW. I believe the cases $n=7, 8$ can be proved by BW.
I leave them for the author of the OP.

---

**Case** $n=3$: Since $a_1^2a_2^2 + a_2^2a_3^2 + a_3^2 a_1^2 \le \frac{(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2)^2}{3}$, it suffices to prove that
$(a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3)^2 \ge \frac{(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2)^3}{3}$
which is true by the power mean inequality.

**Case** $n=4$: Since $a_1^2a_2^2 + a_2^2a_3^2 + a_3^2a_4^2 + a_4^2a_1^2 = (a_1^2 + a_3^2)(a_2^2 + a_4^2) \le \frac{(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2)^2}{4}$,
it suffices to prove that
$(a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 + a_4^3)^2 \ge \frac{(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2)^3}{4}$
which is true by the power mean inequality.

**Case** $n=5$:

Let $b_1\le b_2\le b_3\le b_4\le b_5$ be the rearrangement of $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$. We have
$$a_1^2a_2^2 + a_2^2a_3^2 + a_3^2a_4^2 + a_4^2a_5^2 + a_5^2a_1^2
\le b_1^2b_2^2 + b_1^2b_3^2 + b_2^2b_4^2 + b_3^2b_5^2 + b_4^2b_5^2.$$
See: [farfuridi@AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1425514_variation_on_a_wellknown_inequality),
and the first solution of [Putnam 1996 B3](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/1996s.pdf).

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align}
& (b_1^3 + b_2^3 + b_3^3 + b_4^3 + b_5^3)^2 \\
\ge \ & (b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2 + b_4^2 + b_5^2)
(b_1^2b_2^2 + b_1^2b_3^2 + b_2^2b_4^2 + b_3^2b_5^2 + b_4^2b_5^2).
\end{align}

The Buffalo Way (BW) kills it.
*Hint*: Let $b_2 = b_1 + s, b_3 = b_2 + t, b_4 = b_3 + r, b_5 = b_4 + u$
for $s, t, r, u\ge 0$.

**Case** $n=6$:

Let $b_1\le b_2\le b_3\le b_4\le b_5 \le b_6$ be the rearrangement of $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6$. We have
$$a_1^2a_2^2 + a_2^2a_3^2 + a_3^2a_4^2 + a_4^2a_5^2 + a_5^2a_6^2 + a_6^2a_1^2 
\le b_1^2b_2^2 + b_1^2b_3^2 + b_2^2b_4^2 + b_3^2b_5^2 + b_4^2b_6^2 + b_5^2b_6^2.$$

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align}
&(b_1^3 + b_2^3 + b_3^3 + b_4^3 + b_5^3 + b_6^3)^2\\
 \ge \ & (b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2 + b_4^2 + b_5^2 + b_6^2)
(b_1^2b_2^2 + b_1^2b_3^2 + b_2^2b_4^2 + b_3^2b_5^2 + b_4^2b_6^2 + b_5^2b_6^2).
\end{align}

The Buffalo Way (BW) works.